# Objective-C: How to get properties of an object inside NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I have this `NSMutableArray` of `UIImage` named *camImages*. Then I want to get the `scale` property of an image, but I can't seem to access that using

```
[[camImages objectAtIndex:i] scale] //doesn't return the desired scale property
[camImages.objectAtIndex:i].scale //doesn't work (Error: Property 'scale' not found on object of type 'id')
```

whereas it is possible to get the property if I have a single UIImage

```
UIImage *img;
img.scale //desired property
```

I am newbie to iOS & Objective-C, how can I get the desired property? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

[[camImages objectAtIndex:i] scale] will return

> **NSDecimalNumberBehaviors**
>
> **Scale**
>
> Returns the number of digits allowed after the decimal separator. (required)
>
> - (short)scale Return Value The number of digits allowed after the decimal separator.

whereas the desired scale is of `CGFloat` type:

> **UIImage**
>
> **scale**
>
> The scale factor of the image. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) CGFloat scale Discussion If you load an
>   image from a file whose name includes the @2x modifier, the scale is
>   set to 2.0. You can also specify an explicit scale factor when
>   initializing an image from a Core Graphics image. All other images are
>   assumed to have a scale factor of 1.0.
>
> If you multiply the logical size of the image (stored in the size
>   property) by the value in this property, you get the dimensions of the
>   image in pixels.

Comment: What *does* `[[camImages objectAtIndex:i] scale]` return?

Comment: @AaronBrager Look at the `UIImage` docs.

Comment: BTW - Do not use the property syntax for non-property calls. In other words, do not use `camImage.objectAtIndex:i`, use `[camImage objectAtIndex:i];`.

Comment: So what does it return?  What errors do you get?  What do you see if you do `NSLog(@"The class is %@", [camImages[i] class]);`?

Comment: Or using modern syntax: `[camImages[i] scale]`

Comment: -1 for not describing the failure.

Comment: @HotLicks The error is `Property scale not found on object of type id`

Comment: @rmaddy I read the UIImage docs per your suggestion, but didn't see anything that indicates why `[[camImages objectAtIndex:i] scale]` "doesn't return the desired scale property".

Comment: That is, isn't your accepted answer syntactically equivalent to `CGFloat scale = [[camImages objectAtIndex:i] scale];`?

Comment: @AaronBrager for some reason it doesn't. As I pointed out in the EDIT part of the question, `[[camImages objectAtIndex:i] scale];` will return `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors` instance and I look thru its documentation, it's different from the desired `CGFloat scale`

Comment: @yonasstephen `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors` is a protocol, not a class.  So you *can't have* an instance of `NSDecimalNumberBehaviors`.  If you type `CGFloat scale = [[camImages objectAtIndex:i] scale];` and then `NSLog(@"%f", scale);`, what do you see in your console?

Comment: @AaronBrager I see. I get an error saying `Multiple methods named scale found with mismatched result, parameter type, or attributes` on the `CGFloat scale = [[camImages objectAtIndex:i] scale];` line

Comment: That's a "warning", not an "error" (unless you have "treat warnings as errors" enabled").  Either of the below answers will resolve the warning, but if you run the code, it will end up returning the float you expect.

Comment: @AaronBrager hmm I never changed the preference to treat warnings as errors tho. But anyway thanks for the info!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make your code easier to read and debug:

```
UIImage *image = camImages[i];
CGFloat scale = image.scale;
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have two `scale` method with different signature, compiler may not able to choose the correct signature to use, so you have to tell compiler the type of the object so it can find the correct one

if you really want one line solution

```
[((UIImage *)[camImages objectAtIndex:i]) scale];
((UIImage *)[camImages objectAtIndex:i]).scale;
```

but use @rmaddy answer for readability

Comment: That wouldn't cause a runtime failure, though it might cause a compile time warning.  But of course the OP has not told us what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: @HotLicks it may crash if the wrong signature was chosen. e.g. compiler call it with float return value but the actual object implemented it return an object

Comment: Not if the object and the use of it were consistent.  If the caller expects a float and the actual method called returns a float then everything is copacetic.